# Bootstrap Accordion - Logic On Alternate Click with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an accordion from Bootstrap.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a id="lblm1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa  fa-plus-square" id="faOn1"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square " id="faOff1" style="display:none;"></i> Subject 
        </h4>
    </a><div id="subjError"></div>
</div>
```

I have something like a glyphicon(fa fa-plus-square & fa-minus-square). I need them to change on click using JQuery. So if collapse1 accordion is open/clicked, the glyphicon(fa-minus-square) will appear and the other one will hide. Ive done that by this way:

```
$('#lblm1').click(function(){
    var click = +$(this).data('clicks') || 0;
    if (click % 2 == 1) {
        $('#faOff1').toggle();
        $('#faOn1').toggle();
    }else{
        $('#faOff1').toggle();
        $('#faOn1').toggle();
    };
    $(this).data('clicks',click+1);
});
```

It will alternately toggle the two when clicked. The only problem is, Bootstrap accordion when clicked closes other collapsible item, so the other glyphicon should be change according to their collapsible.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good logic, instead try toggling the classes for glyphicons.

#### HTML

Removing multiple `i` and keeping just one.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a id="lblm1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Subject 
        </h4>
    </a><div id="subjError"></div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

Toggle it's class, this way you do not need to keep track of the clicks.

```
$('#lblm1').click(function(){
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
});
```